# Underscore array operations for array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Underscore provides handy function for array intersection, difference and union. But they don't work as expected for array of objects:

```
var first = {val: 1};
var otherFirst = {val: 1};
var second = {val: 2};
_.difference([first, second], [otherFirst]); // result is [first, second] instead of [second]
```

This happens because JS checks objects for reference equality. How can I intersect two arrays of objects?

I'm looking for some kind of idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've got something which will work for two arrays.

```
_.filter([first,second], function(obj){
    return !_.findWhere([otherFirst], obj); 
});
```

Basically what it's dong it's checking if an object in the array1 is not present in array2 filter that.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`remove`](http://lodash.com/docs#remove) will work:

```
_.remove([first, second], otherFirst)
```

Comment: Does it work when there are more than one element in second array?

Comment: No, that would need an explicit callback. And I just noticed that underscore actually doesn't even have a `remove` method, it is lodash-specific.